# Using a bearer token API back end with an MVC front end (separate apps)

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2, owin, bearer-token

This question seems to have been asked a lot, but I am afraid I need more help.

I have a WebAPI application that uses bearer tokens.  It works fine.

I want to build into my SEPARATE (not on same server) MVC application and use bearer token authentication.

I would like to use something baked into MVC and not roll my own.

I can easily within MVC make a call to the API, get a token, and then request a protected resource from the API adding the token to the auth header and it works fine.

What I need is how to manage login/logout, support of 'Authorize' attribute on controller actions, support of 'User.IsAuthenticated' in MVC, etc.

Is there some config in the MVC app itself that can streamline the use of bearer tokens (like a startup.auth config) and not have to come up with some klugey session object-based way of storing bearer tokens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i implemented something similar and actually your MVC application should not use those bearer tokens to het 'authenticated'. The best that you could do is use cookie authentication in the MVC app, storing your access token in the claims of the cookie. 
That's at least how i did it. So authenticating through cookie in MVC app, and calling REST services (WebApi) with the bearer token. 
Or if this ressembles your 'Kugey session object-based way or storing', please excuse my answer ;-)